# Transparently connect to SSH machine using expect script

Tags: ssh, expect

I have an expect script which runs ssh and eventually results in a shell. Is it possible to run this script whenever someone ssh's to the matching machine, instead of just using ssh? (ideally by setting some config in ~/.ssh/config)

I'd prefer not to create an alias/script for ssh to check what the host is, then run the appropriate shell.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Should your expect script be invoked whenever someone types `ssh someHost` instead of the default ssh binary? What's the "matching" machine?

Comment: Yes, so you would run the command `ssh host-1` and it internally runs `some-script.sh host-1`, but only if host-1 has some config set (so `ssh host-2` would behave normally if it doesn't have the config set).